# How can I create nested AUTO_INCREMENT fields in a table with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, nested, auto-increment

As part of the management application we're making, I'm trying to optimize as much PHP and MySQL code I can, but I have a concern...

Actually, our data scheme for storing a client order is the following:

```
year -> DATE
order_id -> INT(11)
order_line_id -> INT(11)
```

What we basically do is to reset the order_id field each year (legally, and for accountability purposes, you can either reset your id's or just let them grow, although account managers usually prefer the first option rather than the second one), and the same goes for order line id's, so each order has its line id's reset for each consecutive order.

All of this, however, is done by hand. This is far from ideal and I would like to do it in the proper<sup>TM</sup> way, which would be automating the process and handing reset control over to MySQL.

But the question is... how? How do I tell MySQL to automatically reset the AUTO_INCREMENT field for **order_line_id** with each new **order_id** and to automatically reset the AUTO_INCREMENT field for **order_id** with each new **year**?

Comment: autoincrement is for primary keys... in your case the order_id cant be a PK as its client specified information, and has nothing todo with the integrity of your db schema.

Answer (score 1):

well, as long as I know, in mysql you only can have auto_increment on the primary_key, otherwise you have to set these values manualy when inserting/updating the field, however that is not much of a problem.

you can also have key on two columns in mysql, so you could probably have an primary_key with auto_increment on (order_id,year).

otherwise the order_id, for example, would be set when inserting by a subquery where you search for max(order_id) where year=this_year

Answer (score 0):

You can setup only one autoincrement.
BUT you can setup BEFORE INSERT trigger to do update of columns based on sequence.

There are no sequence entity in mysql, so you have do it yourself.

Easy way is put first row manualy, create index on columns with sequence, and use

```
select order_id+1 into new_order_id  
      from your_table_name order by order_id desc limit 1
```

note,that is not 100% correct method. it will give again same order_id if u delete top one.

to get 100% valid sequence, u have create table for it and manage it manualy.